# Can Wordpress user email be created dynamically using PHP server http host, etc?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the Wordpress user settings > email field > is it possible to put something like for example info@($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) or xyz@($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) so that it will automatically use the domain name of the wordpress installation? Similar to the way you can use PHP for dynamic domain stuff...

It would be very useful for cloning/distribution of turnkey WP sites for clients.

[image]

so with added functions code what would we use in the email field?

[image]

Comment: Question: If you do not have info@xxxxx.xxx account in the mail server, what will happen ?

Comment: I suppose it would behave in the same way as if any new user profile was created (without email verification) by admin where it's possible email address may not exist. The intention is to create a dynamic generated info@ or anything@ email address ready to go with the WP migration/clone and then just tell client/recipient to make sure to create that specified email account on their mail server.

Comment: don't most modern mail servers have catch all capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a custom function in your theme's '**functions.php**' file or in a custom plugin. Here's a simplified example:

```
function dynamic_email_based_on_domain($user_email) {
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$email = 'info@' . $domain;  // Adjust this as needed
return $email;
}

add_filter('pre_user_email', 'dynamic_email_based_on_domain');
```

In this example, the '**dynamic_email_based_on_domain**' function fetches the domain from '**$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**' and appends it to a predefined email prefix. The '**add_filter**' function hooks this logic to the email field, ensuring that the email gets dynamically generated based on the domain when a new user is registered.

Comment: Thank you! Adding function to theme or code snippets plugin is straightforward. As far as the text/info we should enter in the email field in the user profile, what would that be? Email field: info@[..............] or other code, to make it work with the function.